# Servlet session without cookies + ajax requests that only return JSON

Tags: java, ajax, session, servlets, tomcat7

Here's my situation, I have a web site that I just load using Apache HTTPD that then makes Ajax POST requests to a servlet which returns only JSON data. That JSON data is then used to update tables, etc..

Now I want to add user logic to my site, and also maintain servlet sessions for requests made by individual users.

I understand that the servlet needs to return the session id generated by the first call to request.getSession(), so that the client can add this sessionid to future Ajax requests in order for the servlet to know which session in memory to use.

I also understand that the two ways that this session id can be returned to the client is either using cookies (JESSIONID) or URL Rewriting.

If I can't use URL Rewriting, because I'm just returning JSON data, are cookies the only way I have left to send back the session id to the client?

Also, as a side question, currently I noticed that there is no JSESSIONID cookie in any of my HTTP responses from the servlet. Someone suggested to me that this was something new in Tomcat7 and that I had to activate them in the global context.xml. Does this mean that by default there is no session handling even if you make calls to request.getSession() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly identified two of the three ways of handling session IDs supported by Tomcat. There is a third way to track sessions but only if the application runs over SSL. In that case you can configure Tomcat to use the SSL session ID.

If the Servlet calls request.getSession() then Tomcat always includes a session ID in the response. However, those cookies are marked as httpOnly by default in Tomcat 7 onwards which means they are not visible to javascript (to protect against XSS attacks that try to steal the cookie). If the session cookies need to be visible to script then you need to set useHttpOnly="false" in either the web application's context.xml (to change the default for just that file) or in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/context.xml to change the default setting for every web application.

Comment: Ok thanks it's true there is also the SSL approach but I didn't consider it because we don't use HTTPS at this point, although we did talk about getting a certificate in the future. Ok so I guess for now I don't have a choice but to use cookies. I still don't see them even with useHttpOnly="false" so I'm probably still doing something wrong, I'll investigate this further. Thanks.